# Closures in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I've been trying to understand how closures work. I understand that they capture their environments, but I don't understand how this happens, though.

In the code,

```
func make() {
    print("Done")
}

func count( f: @escaping ()->()) -> () -> (){
    var c = 0
    return{
        c = c + 1
        f()
    }
}

let countmake = count(f: make)

countmake()
countmake()
```

When stepping through the code, why does the declaration of `c` get skipped, and instead go straight to the anonymous function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You declare the `c` variable only once, when call the `count` function.
2. When you call the `countmake` function, you call only this block (closure):

   ```
   {
       c = c + 1
       f()
   }
   ```

   Because you return this block from the `count` function.
3. But this closure keeps a context. It means that the system saves in the memory all variables which are referred from your closure. Thus the `c` variable is defined only once and available from the `countmake` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely looked past that countmake only holds the anonymous function returned by count.